# OneDrive keeps deleting the same group of files in a directory

Tags: onedrive

I am not deleting these files. It is a specific directory that has OneNote files and only OneNote files. I noticed that there seem to be copies of these files for each time  have restored the files with the computer name appended like this 'fileName-computerName' with '-computerName' appended once more for each restore from trash can. I don't know if this is a security issue or a bug.

Comment: Look in OneNote, History, Recycle Bin, and delete trash in there. Restart the computer and see if that changes OneDrive behavior

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: You said the Files were in One Note.  So I was suggesting you look in the One Note recycle bin to see if One Drive is trying to deal with the One Note recycle bin

Comment: OneNote recycle bin is greyed out, doesn't seem to be available to me.

Comment: I do not know in this case. Sorry

Comment: Is this a business Microsoft/One Drive account? If the recycle bin in One Note is greyed out that makes me think someone has set policy on your system

Comment: It is the bog standard version with Home edition of Win11. No policies.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem, and finally found a different post talking about it.

It seems to be related to the fact that "OneDrive will automatically convert local notebooks from the local OneDrive folder to a cloud notebook that you can open from the app or on the web." (According to [this Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/move-a-onenote-notebook-to-onedrive-0af0a141-0bdf-49ab-9e50-45dbcca44082?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).)

So if you manually copy OneNote files to OneDrive, the files will be removed and replaced with a web shortcut. If you click the shortcut, the OneNote notebook opens in a web browser, but you can also switch back to the OneNote application and edit it there. Either way though, the files are still on the web only, and not visible in the OneDrive folder you copied them to, or even when viewing the OneDrive folder on the web.

However, in several cases, I've found that OneDrive silently removes the OneNote files *without* replacing them with a web shortcut, so the files are seemingly just deleted.

This post discusses the same issue: [Is there a list of files OneDrive surreptitiously deletes?](https://superuser.com/q/1547498/17046)